# Mysql query to fetch records based on max order

Tags: mysql, join

To be more specific I have 2 tables:

```
1. product table:
id pname
1  camera
2  tv
3  fridge

2. Approval table:
id  user_id order   status
2   suneel  1   approved
2   raj     2   approved
2   kumar   3   pending
3   suneel  1   approved
3   raj     2   pending
3   kumar   3   pending
3   xxxx    4   pending
```

Each product will go through an approval chain in the order. So I am looking for a query that will list the records that are pending and the next approval order item.

The query will display only one record for each item.

Expected output:

```
id pname user_id order status
2  tv    kumar    3    pending 
3  fridge raj     2    pending
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific. I don't even understand what the 2nd line means

Comment: Suneel see my edited answer.. I believe it'll do what you want.

Comment: what if a product is not approved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your logic correctly I would start with a query like this that will return the maximum order for every approval:

```
SELECT   id, MAX(`order`) as max_approval
FROM     approval
WHERE    status='approved'
GROUP BY id
```

then you can join it back to the original table:

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  p.pname,
  max_approval as `order`,
  a2.user_id,
  a2.status
FROM
  (
    SELECT   id, MAX(`order`) as max_approval
    FROM     approval
    WHERE    status='approved'
    GROUP BY id
  ) a INNER JOIN product
  ON a.id = product.id
  LEFT JOIN approval a2
  ON a.id = a2.id AND a.max_approval=a2.`order`-1
```

this will return the next row after the status approved, but this does not consider the fact that a product could not be approved, or can just be approved and never pending. Depending on the logic of your application this might or might not be a problem.

Comment: problem with this is your other fields wont necessarly be the correct ones.. max() will not be true for the other columns in the row... so in this case when you  join it back your order column will have incorrect information inside it.

Comment: @JohnRuddell of course...that's the reason why I'm joining it back to the original table, I'm then returning the values next to the maximum approved order